# Captions not showing in Internet Explorer when the application is hosted on AWS

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video, caption, customtool

The captions are showing up on the video in all the other browsers except Internet Explorer. 
Point to be noted is: The captions are showing on the video when the code is run from local, meaning when I try to access the application from a server then only is the captions not showing.

I have already tried using default, default="true", mode="showing" for the track element.

Comment: do you have the correct MIME type `text/vtt` defined (IE is a bit pedantic)

Comment: Please try to post your sample code, sample video and sample caption file. We will try to make a test on our end to find the cause for the issue. It can help us to narrow down the issue and find any possible solution for this issue.